# ¿como reinstalar xampp?

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp

No sé como solucionar un error que me arroja el xampp asi que he pensado que lo mejor será volverlo a instalar, por ello quisiera saber como hacer para "machacar" el que ya tengo actualmente. Esta es la ruta en la que están mis páginas php: OPT / LAMPP / HTDOCS / MIS PÁGINAS.. ¿podría eliminar la carpeta LAMPP y con eso quedaría desisntalado el servidor? (y procederia a instalar como la prinera vez). O si hay otra forma para instalar encima de mi actual xampp por favor ponganme los comandos. Ayudneme por favor desde anteayer que no lo soluciono y no puedo seguir mis practicas. Gracias. Ah, estoy usando ubuntu mate, por eso pido ayuda con los comandos.

Comment: Hola, comentanos cual es tu error con el Lampp (xampp para linux)

Comment: Hola. Cambie los permisos que tenia por defecto la carpeta LAMPP a CHMOD 777 creo (oea permisos totales para crear eliminar ejecutar), y todo marchó bien con lo que quería hacer. Pero luego, cuando quise practicar con base de datos e intenté entrar a PHPMYADMIN, me apareció un mensaje de error por permisos incorrectos. Creo que me decía algo de que tenía muchos permisos. Intentó cambiarle los permisos pero hasta ahora no le atino, me sigue apareciendo error, y ahora me sale un mensaje peor que el anterior.

Comment: Tal vez tú sepas darme la combinación exacta de permisos con el comando CHMOD. De repente se arregla así y no necesito reinstalar. Ojalá.

Comment: Resalto que antes marchaba todo bien, yo entraba a mi base de datos gráfica sin problema.. hasta que cambie los permisos a esa combinación que te digo. Lo malo es que no recuerdo que combinación tenía por defecto antes de que la cambiara, sino restauraría todo.

Answer (score 1):

Quizás sea más fácil corregir el error (y así aprender a corregirlo por si te sucede de nuevo)....

Pero si quieres borrarlo y/o reinstalarlo creo que puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Supongo que descargarías un "instalador" que es el que ejecutaste (**como root**)
  algo así como:
  ./xampp-linux-x64-xxx.y.z-0-installer.run

En la carpeta en que instalaste todo el Xampp (supongo que dejaría la de por defecto) como root haz lo siguiente:

```
cd /opt/lampp
./uninstall
```

Y ya puedes de nuevo proceder a reinstalar !!

Comment: asi es, y cuando instales de nuevo hazlo como root, y ejecuta el lampp desde consola como root.

Comment: @luisgulo Edita tu respuesta mediante el enlace [editar] (https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/114032/edit) para añadir actualizaciones a tu respuesta, revisa [answer], saludos!

Comment: Cuando copio y pego el código que me pones aparece una ventana emergente que dice: THIS UNISTALLER REQUIRES ROOT PRIVILEGES. PLEASE BECOME SUPERUSER BEFORE EXCEUTING THE UNISTALLER.

Comment: @ray sudo sh uninstall